# Easier way to serialize C# class as XML text

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

While trying to answer another question, I was serializing a C# object to an XML string.  It was surprisingly hard; this was the shortest code snippet I could come up with:

```
var yourList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
var xs = new XmlSerializer(yourList.GetType());
xs.Serialize(xtw, yourList);
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string xmlEncodedList = encoding.GetString(ms.GetBuffer());
```

The result is okay:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfInt
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <int>1</int>
    <int>2</int>
    <int>3</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

But the snippet is more complicated than I think it should be.  I can't believe you have to know about encoding and MemoryStream for this simple task.

Is there a shorter way to serialize an object to an XML string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A little shorter :-)

```
var yourList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    new XmlSerializer(yourList.GetType()).Serialize(writer, yourList);
    var xmlEncodedList = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Although there's a flaw with this previous approach that's worth pointing out. It will generate an `utf-16` header as we use [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) so it is not exactly equivalent to your code. To get `utf-8` header we should use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) which is an additional line of code:

```
var yourList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        new XmlSerializer(yourList.GetType()).Serialize(writer, yourList);
        var xmlEncodedList = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Even shorter if you don't do `GetStringBuilder()`

Comment: Thanks, SQL Server accepted only the UTF-8 version.  I guess this is as simple as it gets in C#...

Comment: @Andomar: I hadn't seen this question before... you can avoid some of this code using my Utf8StringWriter class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862063

Answer (score 1):

Simply if you want to use UTF8 encoding then do it like this

```
public class StringWriterUtf8 : System.IO.StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }

}
```

and then use StringWriterUtf8 insread of StringWriter like this

```
        using (StringWriterUtf8 textWriter = new StringWriterUtf8())
        {

            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, tr, ns);

            xmlText = textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method or a wrapper class/function to encapsulate the snippet.

Comment: That doesn't particularly make it simpler - just relocates the complexity (though it does imply a level of reuse).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `MemoryStream`, just use a `StringWriter` :

```
var yourList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(yourList.GetType());
    xs.Serialize(sw, yourList);
    string xmlEncodedList = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: That will be UTF-16, not UTF-8