# How to stop invalid characters in xml with a limited (windows-1251) encoding in c#

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

this one's puzzling me no end.  I need to send an xml message to a Russian webservice.  The XML has to be encoded in windows-1251

I have a number of objects that respond to the different types of messages and I turn them into xml thus:

```
public string Serialise(Type t, object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces)
{
    XmlSerializer serialiser = _serialisers.First(s => s.GetType().FullName.Contains(t.Name));
    Windows1251StringWriter myWriter = new Windows1251StringWriter();
    serialiser.Serialize(myWriter, o, Namespaces);
    return myWriter.ToString();
}

public class Windows1251StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); }
    }
}
```

which works fine but the web service rejects requests if we send any characters that aren't in windows-1251.  In the latest example I tried to send a phone number with 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING' (U+202A), 'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' (U+2011) and god help us 'POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING' (U+202C).  I have no control over the input.  I'd like to turn any unknown characters into ? or remove them. I've tried messing with the EncoderFallback but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are serializing to a `string`, the only thing the `Encoding` property in `Windows1251StringWriter` does for you is to change the name of the encoding shown in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

(I think this trick comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862063/serializing-an-object-as-utf-8-xml-in-net).)

And that's it.  All c# strings are always encoded in utf-16 and the base class `StringWriter` writes to this encoding no matter what, regardless of whether the [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.encoding.aspx) property is overridden.

To strip away characters from your XML that are invalid in some specific encoding, you need to encode it down to a byte stream, then decode it, e.g. with the following:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetXml<X>(this X toSerialize, XmlSerializer serializer = null, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = null, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        if (toSerialize == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        serializer = serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize, namespaces);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then do

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251, new EncoderReplacementFallback(""), new DecoderExceptionFallback());
return o.GetXml(serialiser, Namespaces, encoding);
```