# XML changes after Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I noticed that my xml changes after serialization. e.g.
* the `ns` in the start of the `Message` element disappears
* `xmlns:ns` attribute becomes `xmlns`
* there are new attributes added in Message element -  `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
* new attribute in `Header` element - `xmlns`

How can I keep the original form of the xml and prevent these attributes from being added?

Here's how the original XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Message xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
  <Header version="1.0">
    <Sender>3015207400109</Sender>
    <Receiver>8711200999903</Receiver>
    <MessageID>000D2613F64AC021ED783C084735EC78E53</MessageID>
    <CreationDateTime>2017-03-21T08:00:47Z</CreationDateTime>
  </Header>
</ns:Message>
```

And here's the xml after it has been serialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com">
  <Header version="1.0" xmlns="">
    <Sender>3015207400109</Sender>
    <Receiver>8711200999903</Receiver>
    <MessageID>000D2613F64AC021ED783C084735EC78E53</MessageID>
    <CreationDateTime>2017-03-21T08:00:47Z</CreationDateTime>
  </Header>
</Message>
```

The code below is the (generated) class that represents the `Message` xml.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://example.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Message
{

    private Header headerField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
    public Header Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Header
{

    private ulong senderField;

    private ulong receiverField;

    private string messageIDField;

    private System.DateTime creationDateTimeField;

    private decimal versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ulong Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return this.senderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.senderField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ulong Receiver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.receiverField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.receiverField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string MessageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime CreationDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.creationDateTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.creationDateTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both XML documents are semantically the same. Is the difference causing some issue for you? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two XML files you show are semantically identical.  Thus, I'd recommend not worrying about the fact that `XmlSerializer` inserts XML standard namespaces or chooses a different prefixing scheme than was used in the original file.

If, for whatever reason, you *must* suppress output of the standard namespaces and *must* preserve the prefixing scheme of the original file, here's what you can do.

Firstly, to omit the `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces at the root level, follow the instructions from *[Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625927/3744182)*:

```
var s = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
var  ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
s.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize, ns);
```

Next, in order to *keep the original form of the xml* you must first somehow capture the actual XML namespaces and prefixes encountered while reading the file and save them in the `Message` class somewhere for reuse later.  Luckily `XmlSerializer` does support this: you can add an [`XmlSerializerNamespaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) valued public property or field to `Message` and mark it with [`[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute.aspx).  This member will now capture namespaces encountered during deserialization, and cause those namespaces to be added back during serialization.

Putting these two ideas together, you can modify your `Message` type as follows:

```
public partial class Message
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlFileNamespaces { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns a XmlSerializerNamespaces to use when serializing a Message as the root XML object.
    /// If Message was previously deserialized from XML, the actual namespaces observed will be returned.
    /// Otherwise, a default will be returned that suppresses output of the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd namespace attributes.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlRootNamespaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (XmlFileNamespaces != null)
                return XmlFileNamespaces;
            var xmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlNamespaces.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
            // xmlNamespaces.Add("ns", "http://example.com"); // Or, if you prefer, add this namespace as well as disabling xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd.
            return xmlNamespaces;
        }
    }
}
```

And serialize from and to XML as follows:

```
var message = xml.LoadFromXml<Message>();

var reserializedXml = message.GetXml(message.XmlRootNamespaces);
```

Using the following extension methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXml<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862063/serializing-an-object-as-utf-8-xml-in-net
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/92xX0i).