# what is the best way to convert a class to xml and vice versa

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

what is the best way to convert a class to a XML and vice versa?

I want to convert my class to xml for using [XRule](http://www.xrules.org/) and I want to convert back it to class with early type of properties.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to serialize C# class as XML text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738511/easier-way-to-serialize-c-sharp-class-as-xml-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to easily go from a class to XML, and the reverse. [This tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) does a good job explaining how to do it, and how to finely craft the resulting XML.

Comment: thanks.but I don't want save my xml to file.How I can convert serialized xml to XElement?

Comment: tutorial link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Try the `XmlSerializer` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: thanks.but I don't want save my xml to file.How I can convert serialized xml to XElement?

Answer (score 1):

`XRule` sounds like it plays a similar role as an XML Schema (I'm not familiar with it). The XML Schema Definition (xsd.exe) tool allows you to generate common language runtime classes from XML files and vice-versa. More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks.but I don't want save my xml to file.How I can convert serialized xml to XElement?